# Problem with email server mac os x snow leopard 10.6

Tags: email, mac-osx, mac, osx-snow-leopard

Good morning, we have a problem with the mail server mac os x server 10.6.
The problem is that work email accounts from outside the server location. Ie from home I can connect correctly, and send and receive mail. But not from the office, which is where the server. It happens with the same computer in both locations.
The error is: the connection has been rejected
But out of the office all accounts work correctly.
Can anyone help?
Multidomain configuration is under IMAP.

Thank you very much, and sorry for my English.

Comment: Is your 10.6 server using multiple network interfaces?

Comment: Fixed. The router had a choice of DNS Relay and DNS Client about the isp ip. Deleting entries everything worked properly. Thank you very much for your invaluable help.

Answer (score 1):

Is the office network (including the server) on a private network (i.e. behind NAT)?  You can tell by looking at its IP address -- if it starts with 10. or 192.168. or 172.16-31. then it's a private network.  If this is the case, the problem is likely to be that the office computers are trying to reach the server at its public IP address (which is actually the WAN IP address of the router doing NAT) and the router doesn't support this (it's known as "hairpin NAT").

If this is the problem, the best solution is to set up a private DNS server for the office network, and make an entry in that with the server's name and private IP address, and then configure the office computers to use that instead of any public DNS server.

Alternately, you could replace the router with one that supports hairpin NAT.  But there's likely to be a performance penalty; the DNS approach is really the better way to go.

Comment: Fixed. The router had a choice of DNS Relay and DNS Client about the isp ip. Deleting entries everything worked properly. Thank you very much for your invaluable help.